# Method signature for a function with default values

Tags: scala

In Scala, is there a way to specify that a function should have default parameter values declared?

For example, in the code below, is there a way to specify in the signature of `indirectHelloName` that the provided function must provide a default value for the second parameter?

```
def helloName(name: String, greating: String = "hello"): Unit = { 
  println(s"$greating $name")
}

def indirectHelloName(name: String, function: (String,String) => Unit): Unit = {
  if (name == "Ted") {  
    function(name, "Custom Greeting for Ted!")
  } else {
    function(name) //This would use the default value for the second argument.
  }
}
```

Comment: A function cannot have an optional parameter with default argument, therefore there is no way to specify one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Scala, is there a way to specify that a function should have default parameter values declared?
>
> For example, in the code below, is there a way to specify in the signature of `indirectHelloName` that the provided function must provide a default value for the second parameter?

A function cannot have an optional parameter with default argument, therefore there is no way to specify one:

```
val f = (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b
//⇒ f: (Int, Int) => Int = $$Lambda$1073/0x000000080070c840@6cd98a05

val g = (a: Int, b: Int = 5) => a + b
// <console>:1: error: ')' expected but '=' found.
//        val g = (a: Int, b: Int = 5) => a + b
//                                ^

val h = new Function2[Int, Int, Int] { 
  override def apply(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
}
//⇒ h: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>

val i = new Function2[Int, Int, Int] {
  override def apply(a: Int, b: Int = 5) = a + b
}
//⇒ i: (Int, Int) => Int{def apply$default$2: Int @scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance} = <function2>

i(3, 5)
//⇒ res: Int = 8

i(3)
// <console>:13: error: not enough arguments for method apply: (v1: Int, v2: Int)Int in trait Function2.
// Unspecified value parameter v2.
//        h(3)
//         ^
```

Comment: So, a method can have default values, but a function cannot? is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Methods can do lots of things that functions can't. Methods can be generic, have optional parameters with default arguments, have multiple parameter lists, have implicit parameter lists, be implicit themselves, and have overloads. Functions can do none of those things. You might ask yourself, why do we even have functions if they are so much worse than methods? Well, there is one very important thing that distinguishes functions from methods: functions are objects, methods aren't. And in an OO language, where everything you do is about objects, that is a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could do is move the default value from the parameter list to inside the method.

```
def helloName(in :String*) :Unit =
  println(in.lift(1).getOrElse("hello") + ", " + in.head)

def indirectHelloName(name: String, function: (String*) => Unit): Unit =
  if (name == "Ted") function(name, "Custom Greeting")
  else               function(name) //use default
```

usage:

```
indirectHelloName("Ted", helloName)  //Custom Greeting, Ted
indirectHelloName("Tam", helloName)  //hello, Tam
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried and come up with the below answer

```
    def helloName(name: String, greeting: String = "hello"): Unit = {
        println(s"$greeting $name")
    }

    val helloNameFn = (x: String, y :String) =>  println(x + y)

    type fn = (String, String) => Unit

    def indirectHelloName(name: String, function:fn = helloNameFn): Unit = {
        if (name == "Ted") {
        function(name, "Custom Greeting for Ted!")
        } else {
        helloName(name) //This would use the default value for the second argument.
        }
    }

    helloNameFn("123", "123")
```

Please try and let me know your comments.